# Convert Recursion to Loop or another faster solution

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming

Working on improvement part of the code. Will be another way to make this method faster?  recursion:

```
 public static int MOD = 11380;
public static int[][][][] memo = new int[11][11][11][31];
static int ret;

public static int solve(int L1, int L2, int L3, int D) {
    if (D < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (L1 + L2 + L3 == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    ret = memo[L1][L2][L3][D];
    if (ret == 0) {
     //   ret = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < L1; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= L2; ++j) {
                for (int k = 0; k <= L3; ++k) {
                    ret += solve(i, j, k, D - 1) *solve(L1 - 1 - i, L2 - j, L3 - k, D);
                    ret %= MOD;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < L2; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= L3; ++j) {
                ret += solve(0, i, j, D - 1) * solve(L1, L2 - 1 - i, L3 - j, D);
                ret %= MOD;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < L3; ++i) {
            ret += solve(0, 0, i, D - 1)  * solve(L1, L2, L3 - 1 - i, D);
            ret%= MOD;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

This is part of the code works very fast in c++, but for now, need to convert into Java, but straight converting into Java code led to taking more time... So, for now looking for improvement of existing code. 
Upd.  D - depth, L1 - amount of {}, L2 - amount of [] and L3 - amount of (). (0<=L1,L2,L3<=10, 0<=D<=30) This is task from spoj competition  [here](http://www.spoj.com/problems/AEROLITE/)

Comment: If you're hoping for an answer, please tell us what the code is meant to do.

Comment: Is the JNI not an option?

Comment: What methodology did you use to measure performance?

Comment: this is online competition(as you can see in a link) - without deadline :). For now, need to implement in Java. JNI - I am not able to submit two files(. About measure - dunno...sorry((.

Comment: How fast is it and how fast has it to be?

Comment: @userunknown 5s for the whole program with 10 test cases.

Comment: @userunknown 5s - it is requirement for how fast it has to be

Comment: @userunknown May I ask you to specify what do you mean  "second question"? If you are about JNI - I am not able to submit two files. Does exist any way to submit c++ code inside java one file?

Comment: unfortunately, I dunno due after 5-seconds execution of code was stopped (

Comment: @userunknown I tried with 10 10 10 30 and it takes much more than 5 seconds :( and it is just one test case

Comment: How come your code never assigns to any cell in `memo`?